# Performing survival rate calculation in AnyLogic

Tags: java, anylogic

I am new to AnyLogic (and coding) and I am trying to calculate the survival rate of a population. I set up a function called `Survival` and in the function body I have,

```
double SurvivalRate = agent.Alive()/InitialPopulation;

return SurvivalRate;
```

where `agent.Alive()` is used to count the agent in the Alive state, `InitialPopulation` is a parameter set to 1000, and `SurvivalRate` is variable with initial value set to 0.

I have a dataset and set its vertical value to `SurvivalRate` to show me the numbers when I run the model.

When I run my model, the dataset is only showing 0 as time passes.  I made sure that "Returns value" and Type "double" are checked in the function, but I am not sure if my function is doing the calculation. I tried including the `traceln()` function in the function body but nothing showed up in the console when I run the model. I was just wondering what am I missing in the function.

I am still new to AnyLogic and coding so anything feedback helps!

Thank you!

Comment: Including code really helps others understand your problem and help you with solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your edit! I apologize I did not realize you could do that. Thanks!

Comment: change to double SurvivalRate = (double)agent.Alive()/InitialPopulation; but if nothing shows up with traceln then it may be that you are not even calling the function

Comment: Hi Felipe, thanks for your help! I added a dynamicVariable to call my function and it worked. Thank you!